# Creating a funnel conversion ratio in R considering NA column

Tags: r, tidyverse

I have the following dataset:

```
library(tidyverse)
dataset <- data.frame(id = c(121,122,123,124,125), 
                      segment = c("A","B","B","A",NA), 
                      Web = c(1,1,1,1,1),
                      Tryout = c(1,1,1,0,1), 
                      Purchase = c(1,0,1,0,0), 
                      stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Applying some transformations, is possible to have the conversion funnel (thanks to mr. Akrun for this code):

```
dataset <- dataset %>% 
  select(-id) %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = -segment) %>%
  group_by(name) %>%
  mutate(Total = sum(value)) %>% 
  group_by(name, segment, Total) %>%
  mutate(n = sum(value)) %>% 
  ungroup  %>%
  select(-value) %>% 
  distinct %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = segment, values_from = n)
```

to this table:

```
name     Total     A     B  `NA`
Web         10     5     3     2
Tryout       8     3     3     2
Purchase     5     2     2     1
```

Now the funnel ratio is defined by row operations, for example Tryout/Web, Purchase/Tryout, Purchase/Web

```
name             Total   A       B        `NA`
Tryout/web        0.8    0.6     1         1
Purchase/Tryout   0.625  0.667   0.667     0.5
Purchase/web       0.5   0.4     0.667     0.5
```

I tried to do it row by row, and then bind by row, with this code:

```
dataset_row1 <- dataset[2,-1]/dataset[1,-1]
```

But I get an error, `Error in FUN(left, right) : non-numeric argument to binary operator`

Please, any advice will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: the first row of your dataset should omit two columns so I guess dataset[3,-c(1,2)] should take the numeric columns

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error is caused by you trying to calculate with a non numeric column. On its own `dataset_row1 <- dataset[2,-1]/dataset[1,-1]` works but I don't see your full code of binding rows and therefore cannot tell you what part in your code caused the error. Here is a working solution using `mutate_at`

```
library(dplyr)

new_dataset <- dataset %>%
  mutate_at(c('Total','A','B','NA'),~./lag(.))
```

if you need to divide by only first row instead of previous row

```
new_dataset <- dataset %>%
  mutate_at(c('Total','A','B','NA'),~./first(.))
```

Based on @Manu suggestion, to make this work with a different row number `nth()` should be used

```
row_nr = 1

new_dataset <- dataset %>%
  mutate_at(c('Total','A','B','NA'),~./nth(.,row_nr))
```

Comment: Hello @camnesia, thanks for the answer, I somehow understand the use of lag (it makes me think of SQL), so it divides by the previous value. I have a question, why the use of `~` before the period? Does it make row-wise? And how can I control the division of the third row by the first row?

Comment: `~` is used to pass formulas to create functions on the spot. `lag()` does indeed use the previous row, so this solution would not work if it always has to be divided by the first row

Comment: to divide by first row try replacing `lag()` with `first()`

Comment: You were faster than me on the code @camnesia, I just tried `first(.)` and worked fine. I'm looking in the documentation if second() exist, because a dataset with more rows requires a solution to control the exact row to divide by. Funnels are quite common nowadays. Thank you!

Comment: @Manu `second()` doesn't exist but `last()` and `nth(x,n)` do. I tested this with `nth()` and it also works.

Comment: Hello @camnesia, just to round up the solution, the number of columns could be variable (1, 2... n) so to control that I pick all columns except 1 & 2, I tried: `another_dataset <- dataset[,-c(1,2)] %>% 
  mutate_at(.,~./first(.))` and `another_dataset <- dataset[,-c(1,2)] %>% 
  mutate_at(everything(),~./first(.))` but I got an error: `Error: .vars must be a character/numeric vector or a vars() object, not a formula object`. Do you suggest a change on that code?

Comment: `mutate_at()` does not work that way, you have to specify the columns the operations will be performed on. If you are intending to remove the unnecessary columns and then perform the calculations on the remainder of the columns, you should use `mutate_all()` - `dataset %>% select(-(1:2)) %>% mutate_all(~./first(.))`

Comment: Great @camnesia!, thank you very much! what amazes me is that it works row-wise instead of by column which is how I understood it worked, but anyways it's a great solution!